# Wordpress: Accessing templates stored inside a subfolder in the themes folder

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file, content-management-system

I'm currently using the `twentyfifteen` theme to create my application. Now, inside the `twentyfifteen` themes folder, I have another folder called `tuto`, inside which is a template that I want to use, named `oauth.php`. Here's a couple of screenshots to give an overview of my project's file structure:

[image]

[image]

Now, in order to access my `oauth.php` file, I tried accessing the following link:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/tuto/oauth.php
```

However, I get a `Object not found!` page instead.

I have just started working with Wordpress, and would appreciate some help as to how to access templates stored inside a sub folder which is stored inside the main themes folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login into admin and create new page. on right side in select template section you can see your created templates.  select your created template and create new page. then you can access  your create template just visiting this page.

just read it

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.